# Dynamic/Real-Time Update using 2 different states in Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I am trying to update a visual component giving some information in 1st state, while I make changes in the 2nd State...Question : Is it possible ? If yes,  then is just data binding the solution? how ?!

***Clearer Description :***

**State 1 : Has a form, in which I enter some data value for 3 boxes.**

**State 2 : Has 3 boxes, who have to change in color based on what values were entered in State 1.**

**Purpose : User 1 will enter data in with State 1 open, while User 2 should be able to see the dynamic/real-time effect while he is in State 2.**

Kindly Help as I'm still learning. (If I say beginner, then people get angry!)

Regards,

Chirayu

Comment: The users are on different machines?

Comment: Who gets angry if you say you're a beginner?

Comment: @Flextras, some people actually get angry saying that till when will You keep asking..dunno why though.[used to happen when I used to ask things about GWT on stackoverflow]
@Gregor, The user's are on different machines...its like communicating between 2 different components, in 2 different states of 1 application, being accessed by 2 users on 2 different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's possible using messaging capabilities of Blazeds or Livecycle Data Services.

You can find more info and a example [here](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Creating+a+BlazeDS+messaging+application+in+Flex+Builder)